# Codigo reduzido para insert

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Digamos que tenha os seguintes campos na tabela usuários:

> `ID`,`NOME`,`USUARIO`,`LOGIN` e `SENHA`

Para eu inserir um registro na tabela eu faço o seguinte

```
$usuario = new Usuario();
$usuario->nome = 'Carlos Bruno';
$usuario->login = 'cbcarlos';
$usuario->senha = '123456';
$usuario->save();
```

Existe um codigo mais reduzido para eu fazer esse insert, porque, se fosse muitos campos?

***Exemplo***:

```
$usuario = new Usuario( AllInput() )
$usuario->save()
```

Tipo se eu quisesse pegar de um array

```
Array(
 'Carlos Bruno',
 'cbcarlos',
 '123456' 
);
```

E inserir na base, teria como?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, existe a forma de passar um `array` ***associativo*** no [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) como por exemplo:

```
$newarray = array(
 'nome' => 'Carlos Bruno',
 'login' => 'cbcarlos',
 'senha' => '123456' 
);
```

o `array` de apenas uma dimensão não funcionará, porque, internamente é feito a passagem de valor pelo nome da chave configurada no `fillable`, exemplo:

```
class Usuario extends Eloquent 
{
    protected $fillable = array('nome', 'login', 'senha');
}
```

e para salvar pode ser feito de duas formas:

```
$usuario = new Usuario($newarray);
$usuario->save();
```

ou

```
$usuario = Usuario::create($newarray);
```

Se os valores estão vindo de `input` e uma requisição `post`, por exemplo isso funciona sem problemas.